# Magento 2 - SQLSTATE HY000 2002 Connection refused

Tags: magento2

From time to time this error shows on frontend:
[image: SQLSTATE-HY000-2002-Connection-refused]
When I refresh the page, the page loads normally.
Can someone explain me why this happens? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening for a variety of reasons, but PDO Error is due to the MySQL database connection being incorrect in app/etc/env.php, try a few things:

1. Worth checking the DB permission for the given user.
2. MySQL logs can also give you more information than just connection refused.
3. Check with the hosting company maybe there are some firewall rules which
   is preventing connectivity between Magento and MySQL.

Could you make sure MySQL is running on the server, and you can connect MySQL and the Magento database using the credentials added in the env.php file?

Also, could you check Check PHP-fpm processes running on the server mentioned above?

Try to reproduce from other steps.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, website works well almost always, but from time to time this error shows. After page refresh, the page loads well. What can cause that this error shows ?

Comment: Could you share the website link, this is some of your site when the page loads, there must be a section or part of page that runs some query shows error but when appears in JavaScript the disappear after page loads.

So, you need to perform steps to reproduce.

Thanks

Comment: This error shows on different pages randomly.

Comment: Please share the website or page link.